# Use @var := a.property with django raw sql

Tags: python, mysql, django, cursor

Using cursor.execute(""), django returns NULL anywhere we use @var, but when we print out the cursor._executed and run it in our mysql client, it works perfectly.

Example of our django + mysql :

```
cursor.execute("""
    select 
        @varA := a.property as `my prop`,
        @varA / 100 as `calc prop`
    from
        my_table a;
""")
```

the returned data will be :

```
[
    {
        'my prop' : 1234,
        'calc prop' : null
    }
]
```

What is django doing here, am I missing something obvious ? :S

Any pointers or ideas would be greatly appreciated, cheers

Comment: There is nothing to do with Django here at all.

Comment: Cheers for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have to ask, what is your use case here? [Django's ORM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/) can easily be used to query such a table if it's part of an [`app.Model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/). It's expressive enough to [allow manipulation of values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#some-examples) as in your question:

```
from django.db.models import F

results = MyTable.objects.annotate(my_prop='property', calc_prop=F('property') / 100)
```

Regardless, in special (/rare) cases where you wish to execute queries outside of the ORM, use [raw SQL queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-sql-queries).

If that's still not enough, for really fine grained direct to DB access, you may rely on `cursor.execute()`, but the correct way to do it, as explained [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly), is to fetch the result of the cursor execution:

```
cursor.execute("""
    select 
        @varA := a.property as `my prop`,
        @varA / 100 as `calc prop`
    from
        my_table a;
""")
one_result = cursor.fetchone()
all_results = cursor.fetchall()
```